# Prove that if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n}$ is absolutely convergent, then $|\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n}| \leq | \sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_{n}|$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation

Hey everyone this was given as a practice problem for my first year calculus class and it really giving me a headache, any help is appreciated!

Prove that if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n}$ is absoultley convergent, then $|\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n}| \leq | \sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_{n}|$

Comment: Do you see at least intuitively why it's true?

Comment: Consider what happens when, for at least one $j$, $a_j < 0$

Comment: What tool do we usually use when dealing with the modulus of a sum? (e.g. |a+b|)

Comment: The definition of an infinite sum is the limit of finite sums....

Comment: Yeah I see why it is true but proving it is something I don't know how to do, I've started proving things this year so I'm still tryna get the hang of it

Comment: @AlexChavez As Greg Martin says : The definition of an infinite sum is the limit of finite sums, so for finit sum the triangular inequality works and so.. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\textbf{Hint:}$

Let $\displaystyle S_{k}=\sum_{n=1}^k a_{n}$ and $\displaystyle T_{k}=\sum_{n=1}^k |a_{n}|$ $\;$ for $k\ge1$, and let $\displaystyle S=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}$ and $\displaystyle T=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_{n}|$;

so $S=\displaystyle\lim_{k\to\infty}S_{k}$ and $T=\displaystyle\lim_{k\to\infty}T_{k}$.

By the Triangle Inequality, $\;\;|S_{k}|=|a_{1}+\cdots+a_{k}|\le|a_{1}|+\cdots+|a_{k}|=T_{k}$ and therefore

$\;\;\;-T_{k}\le S_{k}\le T_{k}$ $\;\;$for $k\ge1$.